# Find the limit of $\frac{\ln(a^n+b^n+c^n)}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

What is

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln(a^n+b^n+c^n)}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}$$
where $0<a<b<c\ $?

I tried like this:

$$\lim\frac{\ln(a^n+b^n+c^n)}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}=\lim\frac{\ln(a^n+b^n+c^n)}{n\sqrt{1+1/n+1/n^2}}$$
we know that $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ also $\frac{1}{n^2} \to 0$ and $1 \to 1$ so denominator $\to n$

and here I got stuck.

Comment: Is n going to zero or to infinity ?

Comment: Please edit the question by replacing $n \to 0$ with $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{\log(a^n+b^n+c^n)}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}=\frac{n\log c+\log\left(\left(\frac ac\right)^n+\left(\frac bc\right)^n+1\right)}{n\sqrt{1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\log c$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You have $\ln (c^n)=n \ln c$.  As $c$ gets large, it will dominate the others in the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

Write the numerator as $\ln(c^n(1+(a/c)^n+(b/c)^n))$, and apply the usual rules of logarithms.